# Profanity filter error

Tags: java, if-statement

We would like to give our users the option of filtering out profanity . Suppose that we consider the words cat, dog, and llama to be profane. Write a program that reads a string from the keyboard and tests wether the string contains one of our profane words. Your program should find words like cAt that differ only in case.

Attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cat,dog,llama,x;
        System.out.println("Enter a word");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        x = keyboard.next();
        x.equalsIgnoreCase(x);

        if(x.indexOf("cat")!=-1&&x.indexOf("dog")!=-1&&x.indexOf("llama")!=-1);
        {
            System.out.println("Profanity Detected");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No Profanity Detected");     
        } 
    }
```

It's underlining `else` for some reason so I can't run it. What am I doing wrong?

I am not allowed to use: for, while, and  arrays. We haven't gotten to those yet. I am only allowed to use: boolean, switch, and if-else. Also, I am using `x.equalsIgnoreCase(x)` to discard case identification. Will it work?

Comment: I think that you need to read about the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), to help you understand why your solution might not get top marks ... even after you've fixed the bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
if (x.indexOf("cat") != -1 
    && x.indexOf("dog") != -1 
    && x.indexOf("llama") != -1); // <-- look there

{
    System.out.println("Profanity Detected");
}
```

Do you notice something at the end of the "if"?

Hint the "{block}" isn't part of the if! This is what is causing the "else" to underline.
Perhaps there are additional errors as well, but that's a syntax error flat-out.

I format my code like this so I can spot these errors easily. Adopting good *code formatting* is a very productive task :)

```
if (expr) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got that part figured out but now it's not reading those three words for some reason. it just skips to else. Can you give some suggestion on that?

Comment: @user605989 See the answer by Michael Aaron Safyan -- the input provided on stdin will very much determine what happens. What different test-cases have you tried? Which one(s) fail?

Comment: @user605989 I suspect the problem is that profanity is only detected if ALL the words are present. Perhaps you want **or** (`||`) instead of **and** (`&&`).

Comment: Wow.That was dumb of me, lol. Works like a charm with using || . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lose the semicolon after your `if` expression.

Answer (score 1):

`x.equalsIgnoreCase(x);` is doing nothing.

To convert the string to lower case.
Use `x = x.toLowerCase();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. As EboMike has pointed out, you have an extraneous semicolon.
2. What do you expect `x.equalsIgnoreCase(x)` to do? That will always return true (yes, x is equal to itself), and since you don't use that anywhere, your invocation of it is completely useless.
3. If you are searching for text using `indexOf()` but you need it to be case-insensitive, then you might consider converting the string to all upper case or all lower case first.
4. What about words such as "catherine"? Do you intend to catch those as well?

P.S. You may find reading the Java documentation for the [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class useful. If you are using Google Chrome, you may also find the [Java API Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmemhpnegbemmombomnemddmjgcoikcl) extension helpful for finding relevant documentation. Otherwise, you should definitely checkout and bookmark the [Java 6 API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Comment: I removed the semicolon after if , but it still underlines else. Changed it to Lower case.
Sorry, I didn't get what you mean by " case -insensitive".Can you
provide an example?
No, just those three words.

Comment: CAT == cat. true if your program is case sesitive. false if your program is not case sensitive

Comment: @ Micheal Aaron Safyan, yeah how do I differentiate between the word cat and catherine? I just noticed that.

Comment: You need to split the string, and then check the individual words, instead of searching within the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a detection if ALL profanity is detected: if cat && llama && dog are detected.

To fix this, use || (or): return a detection of cat || llama || dog are detected.

Answer (score 0):

this is simpler than you think. use the .equals method.

Comment: How about elaborating on that? Show how the method would be used in the code, and explain why that resolves the problem. As it is, this answer is vague.