# Profanity filter- Java

Tags: java, if-statement

We have to  filter out three words cat, dog, and llama. Program has to filter out these words when varying in case like cAt.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign5 {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    String cat,dog,llama,x,y,z;
    System.out.println("Enter a word");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    x=keyboard.next();
    y=x.toLowerCase();

    if (y.indexOf("cat")!=-1||y.indexOf("dog")!=-1|y.indexOf("llama")!=-1)
    {
       System.out.println("Profanity Detected");
    }
    else if(y.indexOf("cat")!=-1||y.indexOf("dog")!=-1|y.indexOf("llama")!=-1)
    {
       y.charAt(0);
       y.charAt(1);
       y.charAt(2);
       y.charAt(3);
         System.out.println("No Profanity Detected");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> Enter a word
>
> dogmatic
>
> Profanity Detected

I am trying to weed out any words that contain those three words. It's not reading it. I tried splitting the characters using charAt but it isn't working. it keeps reading the if. Also how I make it case sensitive? It does detect "cAt" as profane but also considers "cat" as profane as well. I can't use: array, for , while or split. Right now, I can only work with if-else, switch, and charAt to split.

@ The Scrum Meister: I posted that one as well. This is a repost since I am still having trouble working this thing.

Comment: String.contains() http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: Before you continue on this project, read this article: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html. In fact, just Google "clbuttic"

Comment: Related interesting article by SO's own Jeff Atwood: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profanity filter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982595/profanity-filter-error)

Answer (score 2):

To point you in the right direction, I'll point you to the [String documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/).  Namely, the equals function.  On StackOverflow we try not to give exact examples for homework, but guide the student in the right direction.  If you have any specific questions about how something works or something similar, we'll be glad to help.

One piece of advice, you don't want to call `y=x.toLowerCase();` because once you've done that, you have no way to differentiate between "cat" and "cAt" (since they are now both "cat").

Comment: @user Check my update for a quick hint.  Beyond that, if indexOf returns a result that is not equal to -1, you need to perform another check to make sure that the characters before and after the words you're trying to filter are not letter characters.  That will help filter out words like "dogmatic"

Comment: @user How is it coming?  Is there anything else we can help with?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the: 
.contains() method
which is a boolean method testing a string, returns true if it has the specified string in the contains("String param here") parameter.