# So I am working on a code that I am stuck on with

Tags: java, filter, indexof, profanity

I'm stuck on an assigment! Please help! the assignments asks

We would like to give our users the option of filtering out profanity . Suppose that we consider the words cat, dog, and llama to be profane. Write a program that reads a string from the keyboard and tests whether the string contains one of our profane words. Have your program reject only lines that contain a profane word exactly. For example, Dogmatic concatenation is a small category. This sentence should not be considered profane. 
I know ==0 is wrong but, I want it to not have the word cataclysm not to be profane and to print out a sentence like "the storm was cataclysm" and not be profane

```
import java.util.*;

public class Profanity {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String words;

System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
words = in.nextLine();
words = words.toLowerCase();

if (words.indexOf("cat") !=-1)
{
    if(words.length()==3)
        System.out.println("cats by itself censored!");

else if(words.indexOf("cat ")==0)
    System.out.println("cat is in the beginning censored!");
else if(words.indexOf(" cat ")!=-1)
    System.out.println("cat is in the string censored!");
else if(words.indexOf(" cat")==0); //<-- ==0 is def wrong, please help
    System.out.println("cat is at the end censored!"); }
else
    System.out.println(words);
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Profanity filter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982595/profanity-filter-error)

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(word.indexOf(" cat")==(word.length()-5);
```

Should work.

Comment: You tried exactly what I typed and it trips on cataclysm?  If `" cat"` is a Substring of `word`, and it makes up the last 4 characters of the `string` `word`, then the index should return 4 less then the last index, and the last index is one less than the integer value returned by the `.length()` method call.

Comment: In the specific case of `"the storm was a cataclysm"`, the `word.indexOf(" cat")` method call should return 15 as `" cat"` appears starting at index 15.  Meanwhile, `word.length()` should return 26, as that is the length of the entire string. (And `word.length()-5` would give you 20, which `!= word.indexOf(" cat")`

Comment: Modify your program and have it print the values returned by all of your `word.indexOf` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is flawed.  It does not handle punctuation, and `" cat"` won't necessarily match the end of the sentence. *eg* `please catch the cat` -- `catch` will be matched and ignored, but `cat` will pass through.

What you need is a loop, searching for *all* occurrances of `"cat"`.  Use the version of `indexOf` that searches from a given index:

```
public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
```

The idea here is that whenever you find a match, you check the character before it and the character after it to see if they are a letter (use `Character.isLetter`).  That's when you do your bounds-checking.  You then start looking for `word` at index `lastIndex + word.length()`, and continue looping until you've examined the entire string.

You can wrap this inside another loop so that you don't have to hard-code all your profane words.  Just put them all into an array, and loop over the array.